# $fclose placement in testbench

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I want to use `$fmonitor` so that an output value is written to a file every time the value changes.

When I place `$fclose` inside the `initial begin` block, there are no errors. However, unsurprisingly, the output file is empty.

When I place `$fclose` right before the `endmodule` statement, I get a syntax error.  Where should I place it?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module fir168_input_ones_tb();
    integer fp;
    reg clk, rst;
    wire tvalid, fir_valid, fir_rdy;
    wire [15:0] inputdata;
    wire signed [39:0] fir_out;
   
    generateOnes indata(
        .clk (clk), 
        .outData (inputdata), 
        .tlast (tvalid));  
         
    fir168 fir168_i
       //(.M_AXIS_DATA_0_tdata(fir_out_trunc),
       (.M_AXIS_DATA_0_tdata(fir_out),
        .M_AXIS_DATA_0_tvalid(fir_valid), 
        .S_AXIS_DATA_0_tdata(inputdata),
        .S_AXIS_DATA_0_tready(fir_rdy),
        .S_AXIS_DATA_0_tvalid(tvalid),
        .aclk_0(clk));
    
    always begin
        clk = ~clk;  #5;
    end
    
    initial begin
       fp = $fopen("simOutput.txt", "w+");
       $fmonitorh(fp, fir_out);
       clk = 0;
       //$display("%d", fir_out);
       //$fclose(fp);    
    end//initial
    $fclose(fp);   
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fopen`/`$fmonitor`/`$fclose` are all procedural statements that must be placed inside procedural code.

When you had `$fclose` in the initial block, you closed it at time 0 before `$fmonitor` had a chance to produce any output. `$fmonitor` writes the state of its arguments at `then end` of current time slot when any of them change value.

You need to let your simulation run for some period of time and then have it execute a `$finish`. There is no need to explicitly use `$fclose` unless you have too many files open at one time, or some other process is blocked waiting for the file output.

Answer (score 1):

`$fclose` must be used inside a procedural block, like an `initial` block.  That is why you get the syntax error when you place it right before `endmodule`.

If you want the file to be written until the end of the simulation, there is no need to call `$fclose`.  The file will automatically be closed at the end of the sim.

Otherwise, you need to pick a specific time or a signal event and then close the file.  But, keep in mind that `$fmonitor` will be active for the entire simulation.  That means that if `fir_out` changes after you close the file, your simulator might generate error or warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

$fmoniotor statement does not do much, except it schedules monitor events at the end of every simulation tick. As a result, the $fclose will close the file in the same time tick where $fmonitor was issued before the first execution of a scheduled monitor event.

```
initial begin
   $fmonitor(...);
   ...
   $fclose()
end
```

You can do several things:

Put a certain timing distance between $fmonitor and $fclose, giving a chance for simulation to do something before the file gets closed:

```
initial begin
   $fmoniotor(..);
   ...
   #1000 // add a simulation delay of some value before closing
   $fclose(...);
end
```

you can place $fclose in the *final* block if you want to close it before exit:

```
initial begin
   $fmonitor(...);
   ...
end
final begin
   ... 
   $fclose(...);
end
```

Or you can figure out some event scheme which will close your file when a certain event is generated.

```
initial
    $fmonitor

always @* begin
   if (condition)
      $fclose()
end
```